# Trigger event on page load instead of onclick button

Tags: javascript

I have tried various examples on StackOverflow about this, but no success.
What I have is this button inside a PHP file on Prestashop:

```html
            <a  class="button btn btn-default button-medium" href="#" onclick="return confirm(event)">
                <span>{l s='I confirm my order' mod='amanpay'}
                 <i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
```

That triggers this event:

```html
        <script type="text/javascript">
         function confirm (e)
         {
          e.preventDefault();
                AmnPy.loadModal();
         }
        </script>
```

But what I need is this script to run when the page loades. Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this in your function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //code goes here
});
```

It waits until the page loads to execute the javascript.
See some examples here https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I think there must be something more simple than this

Comment: I think this is the easiest way to do it. If you don't want to use jQuery you could use window.onload with javascript (note that this will be slower than te above because window.onload waits for everything to load before executing the script, the jQuery option runs when the DOM is ready)

Comment: So shall I just insert the entire script inside $( document ).ready(function() { ? just like that will work? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The event that should get fired when a page is fully loaded is the onload of the body.

So

```
<body onload="confirm()">
```

should do the trick,

Comment: Can't use a body tag inside a php file which is already called within another body. And I don't think it will automatically trigger the function as it is right now

Comment: Would have been great to include that information in your original question.

Comment: sorry, will you be able to help with this new info?